# How to pass the parameter of type byte[] to the AsyncTask function?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

How to pass the parameter of type byte[] to the doInBackground function of the AsynTask class?

When I do something like this:

```
private class Banana extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {
    protected void doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(byte[] data);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate() {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
    }
}
```

I get an error saying return type is incompatible with Async Task for the doInBackground function.

Comment: Why don't you accept the answers people give you? You have several questions and no answer accepted, even though some are OK.

Answer (score 4):

`doInBackground` actually expects an array of `array[]`. So you could use:

```
private class Banana extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
            mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(data[0]);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate() {
        }

        protected void onPostExecute() {
        }
    }
```

or you can send that array as class constructor parameter:

```
private class Banana extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private byte[] data;
    public Banana(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... data) {
        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(this.data);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate() {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
    }
}
```